# Error installing tensorflow, serving in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am installing Tensorflow serving for which I have to install tensorflow in ubuntu. I ran `./configure` command in `tf` root directory. 
This is the output :

```
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: 
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation [Default is -march=native]:        
Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n] y
jemalloc enabled
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] y
Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] y
Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] y
XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]

Using python library path: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] y
OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] y
CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Please specify which gcc should be used by nvcc as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: 
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to use system default]: 
Please specify the location where CUDA  toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
Please specify the Cudnn version you want to use. [Leave empty to use system default]: 
Please specify the location where cuDNN  library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to build with.
You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size.
[Default is: "3.5,5.2"]: 
Please specify which C++ compiler should be used as the host C++ compiler. [Default is ]: 
Invalid C++ compiler path.  cannot be found
Please specify which C++ compiler should be used as the host C++ compiler. [Default is ]: /usr/bin/g++
Please specify which C compiler should be used as the host C compiler. [Default is ]: /usr/bin/gcc
Please specify the location where ComputeCpp for SYCL 1.2 is installed. [Default is /usr/local/computecpp]: 
.................................................................
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --expunge_async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
.........
ERROR: package contains errors: tensorflow/stream_executor.
ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/stream_executor': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/cortana/Libraries/serving/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 813
        _create_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
    File "/home/cortana/Libraries/serving/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 727, in _create_cuda_repository
        _get_cuda_config(repository_ctx)
    File "/home/cortana/Libraries/serving/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 584, in _get_cuda_config
        _cudnn_version(repository_ctx, cudnn_install_base..., ...)
    File "/home/cortana/Libraries/serving/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 295, in _cudnn_version
        _find_cuda_define(repository_ctx, cudnn_install_base..., ...)
    File "/home/cortana/Libraries/serving/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 270, in _find_cuda_define
        auto_configure_fail("Cannot find cudnn.h at %s" % st...))
    File "/home/cortana/Libraries/serving/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 93, in auto_configure_fail
        fail("
%sAuto-Configuration Error:%s ...))

Auto-Configuration Error: Cannot find cudnn.h at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/cudnn.h
.
```

There is no folder called `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/include`. I do have `libcudnn.so` file in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `cudnn.h` in the folder `/usr/include`. I dont know how the configuration file is generating the paths but it cant find cudnn although I have successfully installed caffe whose CMakeLists.txt could easily find the paths to cuda and cudnn installation. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: This sounds like Github issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6850 . Can you try again at Tensorflow head and see if the problem is fixed? If not, follow up in that github issue.

Comment: do you have an NVIDIA GPU in your system. If yes, what do you get when you type nvidia-smi and nvcc -V ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really have `cudnn` installed.
find the installation location of your cuda using -
`which nvcc`

in my case it returns - 
`/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc`

so `cudnn.h` is located at `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include` (**if** cudnn is installed)

while configuring tensorflow, you are asked -
`Please specify the location where cuDNN  library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]:`

here you have to explicitly specify the location of `cudnn`.
In my case it is `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include/`.